# SQLite: the progran not runing on first emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I have an emulator open, but when I launch my application it starts a 2nd emulator rather than running on the one that is already open.

Console Output:

```
[2013-02-24 14:30:40 - AdatBpro] Android Launch!
[2013-02-24 14:30:40 - AdatBpro] adb is running normally.
[2013-02-24 14:30:40 - AdatBpro] Performing hu.AB.example.adatbpro.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-02-24 14:30:40 - AdatBpro] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-02-24 14:30:47 - AdatBpro] Launch canceled!
[2013-02-24 14:31:04 - AdatBpro] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'hu.AB.example.adatbpro.MainActivity activity launch'!
[2013-02-24 14:42:15 - AdatBpro] ------------------------------
[2013-02-24 14:42:15 - AdatBpro] Android Launch!
[2013-02-24 14:42:15 - AdatBpro] adb is running normally.
[2013-02-24 14:42:15 - AdatBpro] Performing hu.AB.example.adatbpro.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-02-24 14:42:16 - AdatBpro] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD412'
[2013-02-24 14:42:16 - AdatBpro] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD412'
[2013-02-24 14:42:16 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2013-02-24 14:42:16 - Emulator] WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\Edit\.android\avd\AVD412.avd/sdcard.img
[2013-02-24 14:42:16 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2013-02-24 14:42:16 - AdatBpro] New emulator found: emulator-5556
[2013-02-24 14:42:16 - AdatBpro] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-02-24 14:43:32 - AdatBpro] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5556'
[2013-02-24 14:43:32 - AdatBpro] Uploading AdatBpro.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2013-02-24 14:43:33 - AdatBpro] Installing AdatBpro.apk...
[2013-02-24 14:44:30 - AdatBpro] Success!
```

The program is runing and database open but when the first emulator wrote nothing. I try again run. The first emulator is there open and open the second emulator and wrote everything on the second emulator.

Its only made on emulator.

it does not run on a telephone.

Tested the kill-server and start-servert.
Did not solve the problem. 
I run anything this happens

Why make this? What I made wrong?

I can not find the solution.

Comment: please explain clearly what do you want to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a console window (terminal window, command prompt, etc) and run:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

That will fix your dueling emulator problem.  It happens to a lot of us ;)  Note: adb can be found in the platform-tools folder under your SDKs folder.